# adding folder path to dymanic URL

Tags: javascript, document-library, jsom

Using a Caml query to get a list of all the documents in a list that has folders. The issue I'm having is how to construct the hyperlink. With list that do not have folders I simply append the document name to path to the list to create the hyperlink. However, in this case with folders I need to add the folder name to the list path and don't know how to acquire that information.

How do you get the folder name or is there some way to get the path of the stored document?

Answer (score 0):

You could get the folder URL by using `ServerRelativeUrl` property of Folder object as shown below if you are using CSOM:

```
using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext("http://localhost"))
            {
                List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("TestLib0");
                CamlQuery caml = CamlQuery.CreateAllFoldersQuery();
                Folder rootFolder = list.RootFolder;
                FolderCollection folders = rootFolder.Folders;

                context.Load(folders);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                foreach (Folder folder in folders)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(folder.ServerRelativeUrl);
                }               
            }
```

Reference:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/517105fe-d2c3-42c1-a301-623328ac81ee/how-to-get-document-library-folder-url?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that out. 

Meantime, while debugging with WDT I noticed fields FileRef and FileLeafRef. FIleRef had the info I needed.